# Operation inside the view in the laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Here is my controller i am taking the blog details from the Blog model and passing it through BlogData

Here is the controller

```
$BlogData = Blog::where('BlogUrl', $data)->get();
return View::make('blogview')->with('BlogData', $BlogData);
```

In the view

```
@foreach ($Blogs as $Blog)
{{ $Blog->BlogTitle }}
{{ $Blog->BlogTag }}
@endforeach
```

The Question is i have the BlogTag coloumn as `1,3,4` which means it includes First, Second and Third Tag

How can i fetch the Title of the Tag from the Tag Model

Note : Consider `Tag::` is the model of the tag and TagName is the Name of the Tags such as `Chrome, Google, Internet` like that

Also recommend whether shall i do these process in the view or in controller itself

### Update :

Here is my Table Structure in image for quick and easy understanding

[image]

Here is my Code :

Route :

```
Route::get('blog', 'HomeController@Blog');
```

Controller :

```
public function BlogView($data=NULL)
    {
        $BlogData = Blog::with('tags')->where('BlogUrl', $data)->get();
        Blog::with('tags')->where('BlogUrl', $data)->get();
        return View::make('blogview')->with('BlogData', $BlogData);
    }
```

Model :

Blog Model :

```
<?php
class Blog extends Eloquent 
{
    protected $table = 'blog';
      public function tags(){
       return $this->belongsToMany('Tag', 'blog_tag', 'blog_id', 'tag_id');
    }

}
```

Tag Model :

```
<?php
class Tag extends Eloquent 
{
    protected $table = 'tags';
      public function tags(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Tag', 'blog_tag', 'blog_id', 'tag_id');
    }

}
```

I changed the view multiple times, as the effect of the comment,

So i post the view code here

views :

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    @foreach ($Blogs as $Blog)
    <div class="well">
    <p>
    <a href="<?php echo url();?>/blog/<?php echo $Blog->BlogUrl;?>">{{ $Blog->BlogTitle }}</a>
{{ $Blog->tags()->toSql() }}

@foreach($Blog->tags as $tag)
    {{ $tag->tags }}
@endforeach

{{ dd($Blog->tags->toJson()) }}
        </p>
        <div><h4>
        Writted on {{ date_format($Blog->created_at, 'F d o') }} | Tagged {{$Blog->Name}}
        </h4>
        </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend you store the tags in a pivot table instead of a comma separated list of id's. This new table would look somewhat like this:

```
blog_tags
----------

id       (primary key)
blog_id  (foreign key referencing blog table)
tag_id   (foreign key referencing tag table)
```

Now you would go ahead and define a relationship between blog and tag:

```
class Blog extends Eloquent {
    public function tags(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Tag');
    }
}
```

Depending on whether you follow Laravel's naming conventions you might need to specify the pivot table name and the foreign keys. This would be the fully specified relationship:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('Tag', 'blog_tags', 'blog_id', 'tag_id');
```

After that you can access the tags by doing:

```
$Blog->tags
```

This will give you a collection of tag models. You could then loop over them:

```
@foreach($Blog->tags as $tag)
    {{ $tag->name }}
@endforeach
```

I suggest you also *eager load* the relationship using `with()`. So you don't run a db query for each blog to fetch it's tags:

```
$BlogData = Blog::with('tags')->where('BlogUrl', $data)->get();
return View::make('blogview')->with('BlogData', $BlogData);
```

Be sure to check out the [relationship](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships) section in the docs about Eloquent.

### Edit

Now I see what the problem is. First off, you don't need that line: (not the problem though)

```
$BlogData = Blog::with('tags')->where('BlogUrl', $data)->get();
// Blog::with('tags')->where('BlogUrl', $data)->get();  <<-- remove that
return View::make('blogview')->with('BlogData', $BlogData);
```

Then, defining a relationship `tags()` in the `Tag` model itself doesn't make much sense. You rather want the inverse relationship:

```
class Tag extends Eloquent 
{
    protected $table = 'tags';
    public function blogs(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Blog', 'blog_tag', 'tag_id', 'blog_id');
    }
}
```

However that also is not the root of the problem. But this is:

```
@foreach($Blog->tags as $tag)
    {{ $tag->tags }}
@endforeach
```

Instead of `tags` you should access the `Name` of your tag and print that:

```
@foreach($Blog->tags as $tag)
    {{ $tag->Name }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score -1):

There isn't really any logic that you could put inside the controller here.  As long as its loaded with `with()`, it should be okay to put in the view.

Try this...

```
{{ $Blog->BlogTag->title }}
```