# Display all blogs which has the tags

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

This is the continuation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28374027/operation-inside-the-view-in-the-laravel). I am learning to use joins with models, but I'm having trouble getting them working.

Here is my table structure:

[image]

Here is my Controller:

```
public function Tag($data=NULL)
{
    $BlogData = Tag::with('blogs')->where('Name', $data)->get();
    return $last_query = end($BlogData);
    return View::make('tag')->with('BlogData', $BlogData);
}
```

Here is my Tag Model:

```
<?php
class Tag extends Eloquent 
{
    protected $table = 'tags';

    public static $rules = array(
        'BlogTitle' =>  array('required'),
        'BlogBody' =>  array('required')
        );
      protected $fillable = array('BlogTitle', 'BlogBody');

    public function blogs(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Blog');
    }

}
```

Here is my Blog Model:

```
<?php
class Blog extends Eloquent 
{
    protected $table = 'blog';

    public static $rules = array(
        'BlogTitle' =>  array('required'),
        'BlogBody' =>  array('required')
        );
      protected $fillable = array('BlogTitle', 'BlogBody');

      public function tags(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Tag');
    }

}
```

Here is my view:

```
@extends('layout.master')
@section('body')
    <div class="jumbotron">
    @foreach ($BlogData as $Blog)
        Tag :{{$Blog->Name}}

        {{$Blog->tags;}}
    @endforeach
    </div>
@stop
```

How would I display all blogs that have the tags?

Comment: Erm...what's your question? I've copied the question from your title into your question; keep in mind that you should always ask a question in your, well, question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter models by a certain relationship with `whereHas`:

```
$BlogData = Blog::with('tags')->whereHas('tags', function($q) use $data){
    $q->where('Name', $data);
})->get();
```